# ImportError: cannot import name 'MyLibrary'

Tags: python, import

I watched a tutorial which was coded in Python about OpenCV. I get an error when I try to import a class. The error is below.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webstreaming.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyimagesearch.motion_detection import SingleMotionDetector
ImportError: cannot import name 'SingleMotionDetector' from 'pyimagesearch.motion_detection' (/home/pi/Desktop/Denemeler/pyimagesearch/motion_detection/__init__.py)
```

Here is my directory tree.

```
.
├── pyimagesearch
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── motion_detection
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── singlemotiondetector.py
├── templates
│   └── index.html
└── webstreaming.py
```

I checked stackoverflow but none of the answers worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: What's your `__init__.py` in motion_detection like?. If it's empty the import should be
 from pyimagesearch.motion_detection.singlemotiondetector import SingleMotionDetector

Comment: What's the content of `motion_detector/__init__.py`? What areyou trying to import there?

Comment: Internet says that __init__.py should be blank so I left it blank. @MadhanVaradhodiyil

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil Now I used "pyimagesearch.motion_detection.singlemotiondetector" as an import statement, It worked. If you can add as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Then your import statement should something like ` from pyimagesearch.motion_detection.singlemotiondetector import SingleMotionDetector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a regular package is imported, this **init**.py file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace.

Since `__init__.py` doesn't have module imports, We'll have to manually import the required sub modelues from the respective file. `SingleMotionDetector` is in `singlemotiondetector.py`, the import should look like

```
from pyimagesearch.motion_detection.singlemotiondetector import SingleMotionDetector
```

Reference : [python Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)